# Nginx and PHP-FPM 502 - Bad Gateway upon uploading large File (60GB)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am trying to upload 63GB file on server but getting `502 - Bad Gateway error`.

Server Details -

- Nginx 1.14
- PHP-FPM 7.2
- Laravel 6

Scenario -

I am uploading 64GB file through dropzone.js on Laravel server. Upon upload file will be stored in a mounted drive (NAS CIFS) directory. File upload works for small files (~6GB).

But when uploading large file, JS plugin show 100% complete but after some time server return 502 - Bad Gateway error

PHP-FPM and Nginx configuration -

PHP -

```
 max_execution_time 600s
 upload_max_filesize = 70G
 post_max_size = 70G
```

Nginx -

```
 client_max_body_size 70G;
 client_body_buffer_size 1M;
 fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
 fastcgi_connect_timeout 1800;
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: With such a large file, it's entirely possible you're still getting a PHP timeout or other error. The gateway error would point to something on the PHP side, I would guess

Comment: I have increased PHP-FPM `request_terminate_timeout` to 3600 seconds but got an error - `sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending a request to upstream,`

Comment: You'll need to update the nginx timeouts as well, otherwise it'll break the connection to PHP-FPM before the PHP process has finished.